# Meaning of Criteria.POWER_LOW for LocationManager

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, android-gps

The [Criteria class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria#NO_REQUIREMENT) is not documented in much detail.
Can someone please explain what `POWER_HIGH` and `POWER_LOW` change exactly?
Is it about battery drainage?

```
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);                
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
...
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, locationListener, null);
```

---

**Update**:
I went through some of the source code. It turns out this parameter is ignored in my example because an accuracy is set as well.

`createFromDeprecatedCriteria()` in  `LocationRequest.java`:

```
    ...
    int quality;
    switch (criteria.getAccuracy()) {
        case Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE:
            quality = ACCURACY_BLOCK;
            break;
        case Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE:
            quality = ACCURACY_FINE;
            break;
        default: {
            if (criteria.getPowerRequirement() == Criteria.POWER_HIGH) {
                quality = POWER_HIGH;
            } else {
                quality = POWER_LOW;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different LocationProviders (gps, network, passive etc). The Criteria class can be used by the LocationManger to automatically select the best provider based on your requirements.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

How the Criteria class is actually used can be seen here [here.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6fa9ad4afcd762aea519ff61811386c23d18ddb2/location/java/android/location/LocationManager.java)
Setting the power requirement to `Criteria.POWER_LOW` would probably just rule out the device using the GPS location provider (since it uses far more battery than the other passive types).